# How do I Update a column with a combination of values from other columns without using CONCAT

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table which contains one column that is a combination of comma-separated values from other columns eg

```
    update K2_Data 
set Long_Desc = (PremiseRef,',',BuildRef,',',BlockRef,',',Location,',',ItemRef,',',Quant,',',Life)
where k2_ref = 431578
```

I have tried various examples from this site including `'+'` operator but can't get it to work.

```
    update K2_Data 
set Long_Desc = (PremiseRef+','+BuildRef+','+BlockRef+','+Location+','+ItemRef+','+Quant+','+Life)
where k2_ref = 431578
```

Any help greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I thought 'Concat' was a 2012 addition and I'm using 2008? If it's not, then feel free to use it :-)

Comment: How you are using `+` operator? Show what you have tried.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the fields you're adding up?

Comment: The types are as follows:PremiseRef - int
BuildRef - nchar(10)
BlockRef - nchar(10)
Location - nvarchar(50)
ItemRef - int
Quant - int
Life - int and the Long_Desc is an nvarchar(max). I probably have a little flexibility on the data types if it makes life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast each of the non-varchar columns into varchar and then concatenate using the `'+'` operator. That should do it.

**After Edit**

```
update K2_Data 
set Long_Desc = (cast(PremiseRef as varchar) +','+BuildRef+','+BlockRef+','+Location+','+cast(ItemRef as varchar)+','+cast(Quant as varchar)+','+Life)
where k2_ref = 431578
```

**After 2nd Edit**

```
update K2_Data 
set Long_Desc = (cast(PremiseRef as varchar) +','+cast(BuildRef as varchar)+','+cast(BlockRef as varchar)+','+cast(Location as varchar)+','+cast(ItemRef as varchar)+','+cast(Quant as varchar)+','+cast(Life as varchar))
where k2_ref = 431578
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I'm fairly new to all this would you mind pointing me at an example please.

Comment: I get the error message - Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '999,X         ,1         ,External Site,1666,80,' to data type int.

Comment: That more or less does it thanks. I changed the BuildRef and BlockRef to nvarchar(1) as it was bringing in the spaces and these fields are generally 1 character. Is there an alternative way as I've just realised that blockref is sometmies 2 chars.

Comment: Ignore my last, I can get around it by changing BlockRef to an int and amending the script. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate `int` with `nvarchar`. You have to cast integers to varchar as follows:

```
update K2_Data 
set Long_Desc (CAST(PremiseRef AS VARCHAR(10)+','+ BuildRef+','+BlockRef+','+Location+','+CAST(ItemRef AS VARCHAR(10)+','+CAST(Quant AS VARCHAR(10)+','+CAST(Life AS VARCHAR(10))
where k2_ref = 431578
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting a syntax error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '+'. Any ideas?